# Calculating an exponentially weighted moving average

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying a fairly simple function to calculate an exponentially weighted moving average volatility in Excel VBA, [following](http://www.value-at-risk.net/exponentially-weighted-moving-average-ewma/). However, I think there is some error in my function that I can't pinpoint, because I don't get the correct solution.

```
 Function EWMA(numbers As Range, Lambda As Single) As Double

Dim mean As Double

Dim x As Double

Dim c As Range

Dim n As Integer

mean = WorksheetFunction.Average(numbers)

n = WorksheetFunction.Count(numbers)

For Each c In numbers

    x = x + (Lambda ^ (n - c.Count)) * ((c.Value - mean) ^ 2)

Next c

EWMA = (1 - Lambda) * x

End Function
```

The values I am using and the target volatility (calculated using a spreadsheet EWMA) are [here](http://www.filedropper.com/ewma).

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** using Ron Rosenfeld's solution:

```
Option Explicit

Function EWMA(Zero As Range, Lambda As Double) As Double

    Dim vZero As Variant
    Dim SumWtdRtn As Double
    Dim I As Long
    Dim vPrices As Variant

    Dim LogRtn As Double, RtnSQ As Double, WT As Double, WtdRtn As Double

    vZero = Zero

For I = 2 To UBound(vZero, 1)

    vPrices = 1 / ((1 + vZero(I, 1)) ^ (3 / 12))
    LogRtn = Log(vPrices(I - 1, 1) / vPrices(I, 1))
    RtnSQ = LogRtn ^ 2
    WT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)
    WtdRtn = WT * RtnSQ
    SumWtdRtn = SumWtdRtn + WtdRtn

Next I

EWMA = SumWtdRtn ^ (1 / 2)

End Function
```

Comment: My guess is one of your variables is not what it is supposed to be.  Add a breakpoint and compare what each variable is to what it should be.

Comment: This is really more of a math question than an Excel question. You need to show us the values you expect vs the values you're getting, otherwise you'll need to wait for someone to come in with both the math and the Excel solution.

Comment: C.Count will always = 1.  I assume you want it to increase by one each time the code loops.  You will need to add a counter inside the loop to accommodate.

Comment: Is it possible to attach the file, sample values and correct value you need it

Comment: sure - just attached.

Comment: I saw the sheet, the function you are passing range and lamba. I think instead of passing E range, you are passing F( where you already square the numbers).

Comment: oh you're right, I don't know how I didn't notice that. that still doesn't fix the issue though - do you think anything else could be wrong?

Comment: @varunchandra  Did you read Scott Craner's comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little bit different way of doing it as a VBA function.  The inputs are an array of prices, which is assumed to be in descending order as you show, and Lambda.  Hopefully, the names of the variables will let you see the logic:

```
Option Explicit
Function EWMA2(Prices As Range, Lambda As Double) As Double
    Dim vPrices As Variant
    Dim dSumWtdRtn As Double
    Dim I As Long

    Dim dLogRtn As Double, dRtnSQ As Double, dWT As Double, dWtdRtn As Double

vPrices = Prices
For I = 2 To UBound(vPrices, 1)
    dLogRtn = Log(vPrices(I - 1, 1) / vPrices(I, 1))
    dRtnSQ = dLogRtn ^ 2
    dWT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)
    dWtdRtn = dWT * dRtnSQ
    dSumWtdRtn = dSumWtdRtn + dWtdRtn
Next I

EWMA2 = dSumWtdRtn ^ (1 / 2)

End Function
```

With your data, it gives the same results as the spreadsheet calculation (within the limits of precision of the data types)

**EDIT**

If you want to input the `3M CAD Zero Rates` as the range input, and not the pricing, then you could modify the above to compute the two relevant prices from the returns data.  In this case, it would be:

```
Option Explicit
Function EWMAV(Zeros As Range, Lambda As Double) As Double
    Dim vZeros() As Variant
    Dim dPrice1 As Double, dPrice2 As Double
    Dim dSumWtdRtn As Double
    Dim I As Long

    Dim dLogRtn As Double, dRtnSQ As Double, dWT As Double, dWtdRtn As Double

vZeros = Zeros
For I = 2 To UBound(vZeros, 1)
    dPrice1 = 1 / ((1 + vZeros(I - 1, 1)) ^ (3 / 12))
    dPrice2 = 1 / ((1 + vZeros(I, 1)) ^ (3 / 12))

    dLogRtn = Log(dPrice1 / dPrice2)
    dRtnSQ = dLogRtn ^ 2
    dWT = (1 - Lambda) * Lambda ^ (I - 2)
    dWtdRtn = dWT * dRtnSQ
    dSumWtdRtn = dSumWtdRtn + dWtdRtn
Next I

EWMAV = dSumWtdRtn ^ (1 / 2)

End Function
```

Comment: this works perfectly and is much more efficient than my solution - thank you so much.

Comment: how would you suggest that I change this to calculate the average taking the Zero Rate column as an input rather than the Prices column?

Comment: I tried to change it so that it takes Zero as Range as its input, and then define vPrices in terms of Zero, but this gives me an error

Comment: A #VALUE error in the cell, if I replace Zero as Range instead of Prices as Range, and then define vPrices as vPrices = 1/((1+Zero)^3/12)

Comment: @varunchandra `average with Zero Rate column`  If the math to derive that is the sam as that for deriving the volatility, merely use Zero Rate range for the Price argument.  If the math will be different, develop that formula, then create a VBA routine to implement it.

Comment: @varunchandra  I imagine you have made an error in changing the formula in your new code.

Comment: if I replace the line "vPrices = Prices" with "vPrices = Prices * 2" for example, I get the same #VALUE error. why would operations for this line create errors?

Comment: @varunchandra Because vPrices is an array, not a constant.

Comment: ah okay - i need to convert the Zero column into the Prices column by using some simple operations. since the Zero column will be an array, how can i use operations on it?

Comment: @varunchandra  Loop through the elements, one at a time.  In the same manner as the present code does.

Comment: i updated the original post since its difficult to express in comments - can you tell me what error i made in the implementation?

Comment: @varunchandra You are trying to access elements of vPrices, but it has no elements.

Comment: @varunchandra  You really need to map out where your various calculations are going, and what the results are; step by step, and compare that to what you expect to happen.

Comment: is it not defined the same way that LogRtn, RtnSQ etc are defined, in terms of an earlier array? how can I change that?

Comment: @varunchandra If you read a `Range` into a Variant, it will create an array.  Read through Chip Pearson's article [VBA Arrays And Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for a better understanding.  Also use the `Locals` window in the VB Editor to examine what is going on with your variables.

Comment: @varunchandra See in my **EDIT** one way to modify the original to deal with using the `Zero` range to calculate the EMA volatility

Comment: thank you so much for all your help, I see what I was doing wrong. really appreciate it.